# Validate input time (in minutes)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to put in a field the input of time in minutes so I create this regular expression in javascript:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('[1-9]+[0-9]*') //the 0 is not a correct value for input

var example = "44445/";
if (pattern.test(example)) {

}
```

My problem is that the program enters in the if also in the string there is the "/" value. How is it possible?Anyone can example me?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the start and end anchors. If you don't use anchors, then the regular expression will only check if the string **contains** the numbers.

Using anchors will make sure that the string contain **only** the specified characters.

```
var regex = /^[1-9]+[0-9]*$/;
```

Your regex can also be written as

```
var regex = /^[1-9]\d*$/;
```

```js
function testValue(value) {
  return /^[1-9]\d*$/.test(value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="document.getElementById('i1').value = testValue(this.value)">
<input type="text" readonly id="i1">
```

Comment: It's correct but now when I put the correct input don't validate it!